# Let f : A → B and let X, Y be subsets of the domain A. For any Z ⊆ A, define the image of Z under f to be the set f[Z] = {b ∈ B|∃z ∈ Z (f(z) = b)}.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

a) Show that $\pmb f$[X $\cup$ Y] = $\pmb f$[X] $\cup$ $\pmb f$[Y].

b) Give an example of a function $\pmb f$ and subsets X, Y of it's domain to show that it is not always true that $\pmb f$[X $\cap$ Y] = $\pmb f$[X] $\cap$ $\pmb f$[Y]

For a):

Let $x\in$ $\pmb f$(X $\cup$ Y), then there exists $y\in$ X $\cup$ Y where $\pmb f$(y) = x

By def of union, $x\in$ X $\lor$ $y\in$ Y

$\pmb f$(X) contains all elements that are the image of an element in X and 
$\pmb f$(Y) contains all elements that are the image of an element in Y

$\pmb f(y)\in\pmb f$(X) $\lor$ $\pmb f(y)\in\pmb f$(Y)

Since $\pmb f$(y) = x, $x\in$ $\pmb f$(X) $\lor$ $x\in$ $\pmb f$(Y)

Again, by def of union  $x\in$ $\pmb f$(X) $\cup$ $\pmb f$(Y)

So by def of subset, $\pmb f$(X $\cup$ Y) $\subseteq$ $\pmb f$(X) $\cup$ $\pmb f$(Y)

Then, Let $x\in$ $\pmb f$(X) $\cup$ $\pmb f$(Y)

By def of union, $x\in \pmb f(X)$ $\lor$ $x\in$ $\pmb f(Y)$

Then there exists an element $y\in$ X or $y\in$ Y such that $\pmb f(y)=x$

$y\in$ X $\lor$ $y\in$ Y

By def of union, $y\in$ X $\cup$ $y\in$ Y

$\pmb f$(X $\cup$ Y) contains all elements that are the image of an element in X $\cup$ Y, therefore, $\pmb f$(y) $\in$$\pmb f$(X$\cup$Y)

Since $\pmb f$(y) = x, $\in$$\pmb f$(X $\cup$ Y)

By definition of subset: $\pmb f$(X) $\cup$$\pmb f$(Y) $\subseteq$ $\pmb f$(X $\cup$ Y)

Since $\pmb f$(X) $\cup$$\pmb f$(Y) $\subseteq$ $\pmb f$(X $\cup$ Y) and $\pmb f$(X $\cup$ Y) $\subseteq$ $\pmb f$(X) $\cup$$\pmb f$(Y) the two sets have to be equal.

help with b) is much appreciated, not really sure how to answer it

Comment: What is the difference between a) and b)?

Comment: Just realized that I typoed, in b) it should say f(X∩Y) = f(X) ∩ f (Y)

Answer (score 1):

To construct a basic counterexample for b), observe that there can be *disjoint* sets $X, Y$ such that $f(X)\cap f(Y)\ne\emptyset$ if $f$ is not injective.